# How to get the object instance by its variable

Tags: python

Suppose I will send `self.f` to a global method,

```
def write_to_report(file_hdlr, content):
```

If I want get the what the object is the `file_hdlr` belonged to.

How to get it ? Because I need to know the file_hanlder is belonging which Class,
and use the class name to do somthing

```
def write_to_report(file_hdlr, content):
    file_hdlr.__self__ # ??? NO
```

### CODE

```
class MemoryInfo(threading.Thread):        
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.f = get_export_file_hdlr(self.__class__.__name__)

class CPUInfo(threading.Thread):        
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.f = get_export_file_hdlr(self.__class__.__name__)
```

Comment: Objects do not have an implicit pointer to their "parent". If you think about it, the concept of "parent" does not even make sense, because when a reference is passed, a copy of the reference is made, and this copy is just as valid as the original reference. Now your object belongs to two different objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

A different approach:

```
class ReportWriterMixin(object):
    def write_to_report(self):
        this_class = self.__class__
        # do thing with self.f based on this_class

class CPUInfo(threading.Thread, ReportWriterMixin):        
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.f = get_export_file_hdlr(self.__class__.__name__)
        self.write_to_report()
```

This way, while your method is no longer "global", it can be made available to any class you like

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the type of `file_hdlr` variable, you can use function `type`:

```
file_hdlr_type = type(file_hdlr)
```

Comment: He's asking how he can get the original `self` reference that contained `file_hdlr`....

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand